# Cannot integrate myBatis to existing Spring Restful Web service

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, mybatis, ibatis

I got a Spring Rest WS, then the requirement is implement myBatis to this one. I tried but getting the errors.

Below is my source code.

Start from `web.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <display-name>SpringServiceJsonSample</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet 
            </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/ApplicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
      </context-param>
    </web-app>
```

Next `ApplicationContext.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="myurl" />
        <property name="username" value="myacc" />
        <property name="password" value="myacc" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/mybatis-config.xml" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="cardValidationService" class="com.programmingfree.springservice.dao.CardValidationService">
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Next step, `mybatis-config.xml`

```
<configuration>
  <typeAliases>

    <typeAlias alias="CardNo" type ="com/programmingfree/springservice/domain/CardNo" />

  </typeAliases>
  <mappers>
    <mapper resource="com/programmingfree/springservice/domain/CardNoMapper.xml"/>
  </mappers>

</configuration>
```

Then in domain CardNo.java(Remove getter and setter to make post shorter)

```
    public String cardNo;
    public String email;
    Date dob;
```

Then `CardNoMapper.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com/programmingfree/springservice/domain/CardNo">

  <resultMap id="cardNoMap" type="CardNo">
  <id property="cardNo" column="CARD_NO" javaType="String" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
  <result property="email"  column="EMAIL" javaType="String" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
  <result property="dob"  column="DOB" javaType="java.util.Date" jdbcType="DATE"/>
  </resultMap>

  <select id="getCardNoBy" parameterType="map" resultMap="cardNoMap">
  select  * from user where CARD_NO=#{cardNo}
  </select>

</mapper>
```

In controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service/cardValidate/")
public class CardValidationController {
    @Autowired CardValidationService cardService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{cardNumber}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public String getCard(@PathVariable String cardNumber) {
        String card = cardService.getCardNoBy(cardNumber);
        return card;
    }
}
```

Last one is `CardValidationService`:

```
@Service
public class CardValidationService {

    private SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = null;

    public CardValidationService() {

    }

    public CardValidationService(SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
        this.sqlSessionFactory = sqlSessionFactory;

    }

    public String getCardNoBy(String cardNo) {
        SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
        System.out.println(cardNo);
        String name = null;

        try {
            name = (String) session
                    .selectOne(
                            "com.programmingfree.springservice.domain.CardNo.getCardNoBy",
                            cardNo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then I run it, I got bunches of error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I search that errors and they suggest that add `@Autowired` in

@Autowired
CardValidationService cardService = new CardValidationService();

Then get another errors:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet rest threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2463)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2452)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Update 2**

I'm not sure do I put the xml file in correct folder. `wex.xml, ApplicationContext.xml, mybatis-config.xml, rest-servlet.xml` located in same `WEB-INF` dir

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

a) On controller class

```
@Autowired
   CardValidationService cardValidationService;
```

b) On Service class

```
@Service
   public class CardValidationService {
```

c) For convention please make all instance variable of class CardNo as private.

Reason why you getting NullPointerException is that you're creating a simple Java bean of CardValidationService in your controller class which does not have any dependency injected as you haven't used the bean created by Spring. Also you haven't declared your CardValidationService as bean in your spring configuration so even spring won't be creating that class as a spring-bean.

Comment: Hi, I defined the bean in ApplicationContext.xml, add section a and b as your answer above, but I still got same problem: NullPointerException. It's seem like this part is incorrect: <property name="configLocation" value="mybatis-config.xml" /> I put mybatis-config.xml in WEB-INF dir.

Comment: Hi @Avis. I added a full stack trace in the post, please look at update section. Thanks.

Comment: Yes its the same issue. Can you update the controller & service class above completely except the imports !!!

Comment: I see its still **@Autowired CardService cardService** rather than **@Autowired CardValidationService cardValidationService** . Also i see the method **getCard** is being called on service within the controller class while on the service class we dont have any such method. Again i cant see the setter of **SqlSessionFactory** in the service class. Pls correct n reverify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89906/discussion-between-avis-and-tran-tam-14).

Comment: did this ever get resolved? i've been trying for days to find a demo of a successful mybatis/rest app with no luck